# Считывание целых чисел с файла

Tags: java, filestream

Как считать массив целых чисел из текстового файла, где каждое число записано в новой строке?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы формат файла. Числа могут быть через пробел, построчно.. Мало ли ещё как, бинарный файл с массивом intов.

Comment: @vp_arth, вы полипрограммист? И в JS и Java... где я вас ещё встречу?)

Comment: @Yuri, да где угодно) Мы всё могём)

Comment: @vp_arth, интересный вы человек. Я бы пообщался с вами. Загляните в мой чат (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri) как нибудь :)

Comment: добавлю в закладки)

Comment: Опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы можно было дать нормальный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать для этого [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("in.txt")))
{
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(numbers);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

При необходимости можно создать массив на основе полученного списка:

```
Integer[] array = numbers.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```